# ctrl+c not sending SIGKILL to process

Tags: c, linux, sigkill

I have tried implementing this function:

```
void alarm_handler(int signal)
{
    if(signal==SIGKILL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"Process killed\n");
        exit(SIGKILL);
    }
}
```

And used it in main this way:

```
signal(SIGKILL,alarm_handler);
```

So if I press ctrl+c, before exiting it shall print "Process killed", but id does not print it.Why?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control-C

Comment: And furthermore, SIGKILL cannot be caught ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGKILL ).

Answer (score 14):

Ctrl+C usually sends `SIGINT`, not `SIGKILL`.

Comment: Not usually, but always (unless you configure the terminal tty in very weird ways) is Ctrl-C sending `SIGINT`

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch: I didn't want to exclude the possibility of a weird terminal. It is possible to write one / configure one that sends `SIGKILL` instead of `SIGINT` :)

Answer (score 3):

The signals SIGKILL and SIGSTOP cannot be caught, blocked, or ignored.

Use SIGINT.